# How to unit test a Close Modal function for closing a modal dialog container?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am totally new to unit testing and have no idea about it, so I want help unit testing a javascript modal function which is responsible for closing a modal dialog container. I just want to unit test the **closeModal()** function.

**Javascript part**

```js
 closeModal() {
    const mod = document.getElementsByClassName('mat-dialog-container');
    mod[0].classList.add('close-modal-animation');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dialog.closeAll();
    }, 500);
  }
```

```css
**Html part**
```

```html
<ng-template #callDialog>
  <div class="modal-base">
    <span
      [ngClass]="{'icon-close' : closeButton}"
      (click)="closeModal()"
    ></span>
  </div>
  <mat-dialog-content>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </mat-dialog-content>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: To create a Unitest we want to be sure about what you want to test in this Function. for example "I want to test it return the number 3". please be clear about what you want to test in this Unitest.

Comment: I want to test the set time out thing inside it